# How to split string into multiple columns then stack into one column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(C2:C22," "))

How can I combine the output of this formula into one column vertically?

Example output:

[image: output]

**Note: I'm not looking to combine strings to fit in a single cell. I'm looking for every value to be stacked vertically.

Comment: Please note: Excel is not Google Sheets. Excel does not have `ARRAYFORMULA` or `SPLIT`. Please only use appropriate tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FLATTEN` formula to convert the output into a vertical list:

```
=FLATTEN(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(C2:C22," ")))
```